# SpringHibernate - set up mysql tables for a Simple Blogging app

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating a simple blogging application using Spring Boot by following ( an incomplete )tutorial at:  http://www.nakov.com/blog/2016/08/05/creating-a-blog-system-with-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jpa-and-mysql/#comment-406107.

The model entity classes are as follows, Post and User:

First the code for Post:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
public class Post {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(nullable=false, length = 300)
private String title;

@Lob @Column(nullable=false)
private String body;

@ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private User author;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Date date = new Date();

public Post() {

}

public Post(long id, String title, String body, User author) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.author = author;
}
```

And this is the code for User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false, length=30, unique=true)
private String username;

@Column(length=60)
private String passwordHash;

@Column(length=100)
private String fullName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="author")
private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

public User() {

}

public User(Long id, String username, String fullName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
```

Note that I have omitted package, imports, and getter/setters for convenience.

Just in case, I include my application.properties file:

```
   spring.thymeleaf.cache = false
        server.ssl.enabled=false
        spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/blog_db
        spring.datasource.username=root
        spring.datasource.password=somepassword



    #Configure Hibernate DDL mode: create/update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernmate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

I want to create a corresponding database for my code to hook up to using mysql community server ( the workbench, to be more specific ) and since I'm completely unfamiliar with mysql I'm not having any success.  ( The tut author failed to provide db script so I'm trying to recreate it ).

I'm hoping someone would be willing to help me out with the mysql database scripting.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood how hibernate works.  It appears as if all I need to do is create the database schema blog_db and that provided my application properties are correct hibernate instantiates the tables itself!  Wow... whole new level of awesomeness.... Guessing I answered my own question :)  lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the needed dependencies in your pom.xml

```
 <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and don't forget to add this line to your application.properties.Once you have run your project replace create to update or none this will avoid the inherent drop of a table to create a new one.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

If you have any questions the following link will be a good start

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/